# python: zipping large file with lots of smaller files skips lines in large file

Tags: python-3.x

I have a few small files (f1 and f2) and a "large" file (f3):

```
In [1]: cat f1
1
2
3
4
5
6

In [2]: cat f2
1
2
3
4
5
6


In [3]: cat f3
a
b
c
d
e
f
g
h
i
j
k
l


In [4]: small_files = ['f1', 'f2']
```

I want to `zip` the lines in the large file with the lines in the small files so that I get pairs like:

```
('a\n', '1\n')
('b\n', '2\n')
('c\n', '3\n')
('d\n', '4\n')
('e\n', '5\n')
('f\n', '6\n')
('g\n', '1\n')
('h\n', '2\n')
('i\n', '3\n')
('j\n', '4\n')
('k\n', '5\n')
('l\n', '6\n')
```

But when I try this, the first line from the large file in the second batch
('g') gets skipped:

```
In [5]: with open('f3') as f3:
   ...:     for small_file in small_files:
   ...:         with open(small_file) as s_fobj:
   ...:             for i1, i2 in zip(f3, s_fobj):
   ...:                 print((i1, i2))
   ...:
('a\n', '1\n')
('b\n', '2\n')
('c\n', '3\n')
('d\n', '4\n')
('e\n', '5\n')
('f\n', '6\n')
('h\n', '1\n')
('i\n', '2\n')
('j\n', '3\n')
('k\n', '4\n')
('l\n', '5\n')
('\n', '6\n')
```

I'd like to understand why this is happening and if there's a way I can modify the code above, still using `zip`, to get the desired pairings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is happening here:

```
for i1, i2 in zip(f3, s_fobj):
```

`zip` takes a value from `f3`, and *then* a value from `s_fobj`. Since `s_fobj` reached end of file, `zip` stops (with the shortest sequence).

But the data read from `f3` isn't put back in the `f3` stream. It's just discarded.

A workaround would be to put the shortest sequence as first parameter.

```
for i2, i1 in zip(s_fobj, f3):
```

since `s_fobj` will stop first, `f3` isn't consumed.

A quick test by my end yields:

```
('a\n', '1\n')
('b\n', '2\n')
('c\n', '3\n')
('d\n', '4\n')
('e\n', '5\n')
('f\n', '6\n')
('g\n', '1\n')  <==== the "g" is here, yay!
('h\n', '2\n')
('i\n', '3\n')
('j\n', '4\n')
('k\n', '5\n')
('l\n', '6\n')
```